# Select matching counted Values with other Tables Value using SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

i am new to this forum and also to SQL and need to do a quick view at work. I searched for a topic like this, but didn't find the exact same problem...

I have 2 Tables: TableA and TableB

TableA

```
Name    NumberOfScreens
-----------------------
ABC1          5
ABC2          4
ABC3          7
```

TableB

```
Name   Date   Duration
------------------------
ABC1    x        xxx
ABC1    x        xxx
ABC1    x        xxx
ABC3    x        xxx
ABC3    x        xxx
```

My Problem now is to count the number of equal names in TableB and (thats how I think of it)

```
Select(*) from TableB where Count(Name) <> TableA.NumberOfScreens
```

So if ABC1 appears 5 times in TableB and TableA.NumberOfScreens of ABC1 = 5, i dont want it to appear in my SELECT.
If ABC3 appears 3 Times in TableB and TableA.NumberOfScreens of ABC3 = 5, i need it to appear in my SELECT.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks :)

Comment: Can you be more precise on the expected result ?

Comment: I need to get all Names from Columns from TableB where the Number occurences in TableB is lower than the Number in TableA. A little example:
ABC1 appears 3 times in TableB, but the TableA.NumberOfScreens for ABC1 = 5, so i need it to be selected. 
ABC3 appears 4 times in TableB and the TableA.NumberOfScreens for ABC3 = 4, so there is no need to be selected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select A.Name, A.NumberOfScreens 
from TableA A join TableB B
on A.Name = B.Name
group by A.Name,A.NumberOfScreens 
having count(*) = A.NumberOfScreens
```

Edit:

> ```
> select tb.Name, tb.Date, tb.Duration 
> from TableB tb join 
> (
> select A.Name tmpName, A.NumberOfScreens tmpNumberOfScreen
> from TableA A join TableB B
> on A.Name = B.Name
> group by A.Name,A.NumberOfScreens 
> having count(*) <> A.NumberOfScreens
> ) tmp
> on tb.name = tmp.tmpName
> ```

Comment: that gives me the values from TableA, but i need the columns of TableB :)

Comment: You can join result of this with tableB

Comment: could you give me a little help? As i said, i am new to sql and i just cannot get the result i want :(

Comment: Sorry I missed it. Updated the answer, It may help.

Comment: No Problem :)
But there are still Values from exist 5 times in B and although the value in A is 5, they are selected :/